# Understanding a 'this' pointer

Tags: arduino

I was trying to create my own Servo Write class so I can better understand how PWM works. I basically copied the Servo::write function from Servo.h and tried to paste it into my code, however I don't get what the "this" error is.

```
#include "Servo.h"

#define SERVO_MIN() (MIN_PULSE_WIDTH - this->min * 4)  // minimum value in uS for this servo
#define SERVO_MAX() (MAX_PULSE_WIDTH - this->max * 4)  // maximum value in uS for this servo 

Servo leftServo, rightServo;

int leftServoPos = 90;
int rightServoPos = 90;
int count;

void setup()
{

 leftServo.attach(5);
 rightServo.attach(8);

 leftServo.write(90);
 rightServo.write(90); 

}

void loop()
{

  delay(3000);

  for(count = 1; count < 100; count++)
  {

      leftServo.write(leftServoPos + count);
      rightServo.write(rightServoPos - count);

  }

  delay(1000);

  for(count = 1; count < 100; count++)
  {

      leftServo.write(leftServoPos - count);
      rightServo.write(rightServoPos + count);

  }

}

void writeServo(Servo servo, int value)
{  
  if(value < MIN_PULSE_WIDTH)
  {  // treat values less than 544 as angles in degrees (valid values in microseconds are handled as microseconds)
    if(value < 0) value = 0;
    if(value > 180) value = 180;
    value = map(value, 0, 180, SERVO_MIN(),  SERVO_MAX());      
  }
  this->writeMicroseconds(value);
}
```

Errors:

```
sketch_jun11a.ino: In function 'void writeServo(Servo, int)':
sketch_jun11a:59: error: invalid use of 'this' in non-member function
sketch_jun11a:59: error: invalid use of 'this' in non-member function
sketch_jun11a:61: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'Servo'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this ->
```

is called a this pointer, the pointer is implicitly created and points to invoking object of a member function.

since your function is not in a class the pointer does not exist.

Comment: How would I go around that then? Is it silly to try and do that, or should I just use the files given. My longterm plan was just to use bit shifting to control the servo.

Comment: I would fork the existing files, maybe change the namespace and file name. then work from there. Also if you are going to work on this level maybe brush up on c++ and oo a bit.

Comment: If you are asking what "this" means, chances are that you will hit similar walls with C++ very often.
If you really care about learning C++, try specialized sites for it.
It's far simpler to get the hangs of C++ alone without the extra hurdle of Arduino/embedded programming.

Answer (score 1):

```
this->writeMicroseconds(value);
```

is a member function of the class you copied the code from. The 'this' pointer, basically means 'a pointer to myself', so this is saying 'call the writeMicroseconds() method in my class'.

To fix the error, just copy the writeMicroseconds() method over to your sketch, and remove the this-> from the method call.